# Where should I ask DLL-related questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where should ask the question which are related to DLL files?

The dll-related question is:

> When i try to install a game, an error appears saying "Internal Error : Extract Temporary File: The file "BASS.dll" was not found."

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: This is way too broad. Maybe include an example of the question you would like to ask so we can better judge what you need.

Comment: When i try to install a game, an error appears saying "Internal Error : Extract Temporary File: The file "BASS.dll" was not found."

Answer (score 8):

I think that should be on a support site / forum of the publisher of the game.

*Maybe*, if the problem is commonly known, it might also pop up on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but I won't really suggest to post this question there. The problem is too unclear to say something useful about it.